# Zxing library for QR code reading, downloads an APK from the market

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I have an assignment to make a QR code reader integrated in our application.

I have used the `Zebra Crossing (ZXing)` library, the problem with this library is that, it redirects to the market to download an APK file to scan QR and Bar code.

Is there any library that can be integrated in an application without downloading any kind of apk from the market.

Any suggestions on this would be helpful.

Comment: Use Zxing source code and integrate it with your application.

Comment: I added the library of the source code to my application but it still asks me "This application requires Barcode Scanner. Would you like to install it?" , it makes me direct to the Android MArket.

Comment: "the problem with this library is that, it redirects to the market to download an APK file to scan QR and Bar code." -- That is not a "problem" that is the way the platform designers intended for applications to integrate with one another. If every application that wants to scan barcodes copies this source into their own project the result is that a user with several applications capable of scanning will have several copies of the same program thus wasting space needlessly. I promise you that your life will be easier if you integrate with intents.

Comment: I would agree to you on that Tim, its just a requirement which I am asked to complete. Thanks though I finally found the answer to it over here `http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/`

Answer (score 2):

You should use intents for this task instead of reinventing the wheel. Look at [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.dk/2012/02/share-with-intents.html) example from google. That is how it is intended to work.